# Refresh ListView on another Content Page via button click event

Tags: xamarin

I am having a hard time refreshing a listView. I've tried using ObservableCollection instead of List for contacts but it didn't help. Can someone points me to the right direction please? Any help would be very much appreciated.

ContactListPage.cs file (This is the default page. Add Contact button loads up NewContactPage.)

```
public class ContactListPage : ContentPage
{
    public ListView listView = new ListView();
    public List<Contact> contacts { get; set; }

    public ContactListPage()
    {
        Button button = new Button
        {
            Text = "Add Contact",
            Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 10, 0)
        };
        button.Clicked += OnButtonClicked;

        StackLayout buttonLayout = new StackLayout { Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            Children =
            {
                new Label {Text = "Contact List", FontSize = 30, FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold | FontAttributes.Italic, Margin = new Thickness(10,0,0,0)},
                new Label {Text = "", FontSize = 30, FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold | FontAttributes.Italic, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand},
                button
            }
        };
        contacts = new List<Contact>
        {
            // Add some contacts
            new Contact("Jason", "Bourne", "Family"),
            new Contact("Sunny", "An", "Family Dog"),
            new Contact("Jenny", "Bahn", "Family"),
            new Contact("Joshua", "Brown", "Work")
        };

        // Set up listview 
        listView.ItemsSource = contacts;
        listView.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(TextCell));
        listView.ItemTemplate.SetBinding(TextCell.TextProperty, "FullName");
        listView.ItemTemplate.SetBinding(TextCell.DetailProperty, "ContactType");
        listView.HeightRequest = (40 * contacts.Count);

        // Add things to the stacklayout
        StackLayout layout = new StackLayout();
        layout.Children.Add(buttonLayout);
        layout.Children.Add(listView);

        Content = layout;

        void OnButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            Navigation.PushAsync(new NewContactPage());
        };
    }
}
```

Contact.cs file

```
public class Contact
{
    // constructor
    public Contact(string firstName, string lastName, string contactType)
    {
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
        ContactType = contactType;
    }

    // properties
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string ContactType { get; set; }
    public string FullName
    {
        get
        {
            return FirstName + " " + LastName;
        }
        set
        {
            FullName = value;
        }
    }
}
```

NewContactPage.cs file (Save button seems to be working. I've used Debug.WriteLine to see the list of contacts prior and after adding a new contact. Return button suppose to refresh the contactPage.listView.ItemSource with the latest contents of contacts but it doesn't.)

```
public NewContactPage()
    {
        ContactListPage contactPage = new ContactListPage();

        // Setup tableview
        EntryCell firstName = new EntryCell {Label = "First Name:", Keyboard = Keyboard.Default};
        EntryCell lastName = new EntryCell {Label = "Last Name:", Keyboard = Keyboard.Default};
        EntryCell contactType = new EntryCell {Label = "Contact Type:", Keyboard = Keyboard.Default};
        Label firstLabel = new Label { Text = "", FontSize = 10, FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold | FontAttributes.Italic, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand};
        Label secondLabel = new Label {Text = "", FontSize = 10, FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold | FontAttributes.Italic, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand};
        TableView tableView = new TableView {VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start, Intent = TableIntent.Form,
            Root = new TableRoot("Table Title") {
                new TableSection ("Add a New Contact") {
                    firstName,
                    lastName,
                    contactType
                }
            }
        };

        // Setup buttons
        Button saveContactButton = new Button {Text = "Save Contact", WidthRequest = 150, Margin = new Thickness(50, 0, 0, 0)};
        saveContactButton.Clicked += saveContactButtonClicked;
        Button returnButton = new Button {Text = "Return", WidthRequest = 150, Margin = new Thickness(10, 0, 50, 0)};
        returnButton.Clicked += returnButtonClicked;

        StackLayout buttonLayout = new StackLayout {Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start,
            Children =
            {
                saveContactButton,
                new Label {Text = "", FontSize = 30, FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold | FontAttributes.Italic, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand},
                returnButton
            }
        };

        Content = new StackLayout {Children = { tableView, buttonLayout, firstLabel, secondLabel }};

        void saveContactButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (var yeah in contactPage.contacts)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(yeah.FirstName.ToString());
                }
                // Add new contact to list
                contactPage.contacts.Add(new Contact(firstName.Text.ToString(), lastName.Text.ToString(), contactType.Text.ToString()));
                foreach (var yeah in contactPage.contacts)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(yeah.FullName.ToString());
                }

                firstName.Text = String.Empty;
                lastName.Text = String.Empty;
                contactType.Text = String.Empty;
                DisplayAlert("Success", "New contact has been added.", "OK");

            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", ex);
            }
        };

        void returnButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            contactPage.listView.ItemsSource = null;
            contactPage.listView.ItemsSource = contactPage.contacts;
            Navigation.PopAsync();
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: NewContactPage is creating a NEW copy of ContactListPage.  This is completely separate from the ContactListPage that already exists in memory.  Changes made to one will have no effect on the other one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jason said, in the constructor of `NewContactPage` you are creating a new instance of `ContactListPage` which is completely different than the page you came from (and will return to upon `PopAsync()`).

To make it so you are adding the new contact to the correct page, I suggest passing in the your `ContactListPage` in the constructor of the `NewContactPage`:

```
public NewContactPage(ContactListPage contactPage)
{
    //As a side note it's probably better practice to make
    //contactPage a private variable for the NewContactPage class
    //...
}
```

Then in your `ContactListPage` change the button click method to pass in the page:

```
void OnButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    Navigation.PushAsync(new NewContactPage(this));
};
```

Hope this helps!